# How to create count query on MongoRepository

Tags: spring, mongodb, count

I am creating a MongoRepository and need to create a count query.  Can someone provide an example of what is the best way to do this via the SpringData MongoDB MongoRepository facility? All the examples I was able to find reference returning a List but not counts.

Here is what I am trying to do (obviously it does not work):

```
public interface SchoolRepository extends MongoRepository<School, String> {
    @Query("db.school.count({studentStatus: ?0});")
    int getCountOfStudents(int studentStatus);
}
```

Thanks.
-AP_

Answer (score 1):

I found this question as I was trying to do something similar. Unfortunately, given what I see in [org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-commons/blob/master/spring-data-commons-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/query/parser/PartTree.java):

```
private static final Pattern PREFIX_TEMPLATE = Pattern.compile("^(find|read|get)(\\p{Upper}.*?)??By");
```

It does not appear to be supported.

Instead, we can add custom behaviour to the repository (see [reference manual section 1.4.1](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour)) by creating a new interface and a class that implements it.

```
public interface SchoolRepository extends CrudRepository<School, String>, SchoolRepositoryCustom {
    // find... read... get...
}

public interface SchoolRepositoryCustom {
    int getCountOfStudents(int studentStatus);
}

@Service
public class SchoolRepositoryImpl implements SchoolRepositoryCustom {
    @Autowired
    private SchoolRepository schoolRepository;

    public int getCountOfStudents(int studentStatus) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that the class is named SchoolRepositoryImpl, not SchoolRepositoryCustomImpl.